# Region argument in pyautogui screenshot function

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to take a screenshot of a specific part of my desktop but no matter what coordinates I pass to the region argument in the screenshot function, I get an image of entire desktop. I have used multiple coordinate options but still the same result. any help would be appreciated.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.screenshot(region=(500,500,100,100))

pyautogui.screenshot(region=(10,20,200,400))

pyautogui.screenshot(region=(50,100,100,100))

pyautogui.screenshot(region=(300,400,500,1000))
```

These all return the same screenshot of entire desktop.

Comment: I am using Mac with macOS Mojave version 10.14.3

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Here is the code I used:

Comment: You could take a look at [this documentaion](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function), it's a good description.

Comment: @yghan are you running each line of them alone or all of them at once?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres I am running them individually. just trying to give you an idea of the types of coordinates that I used where the results were a screenshot of entire desktop.

Comment: They return the right screenshots for me

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBres are you running on Mac with Mojave version 10.14.3?

Comment: No, I use Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to a variable:

```
ss = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(500,500,100,100))
```